# Can TravisCI create new files?

Tags: python, travis-ci, pytest

The following block of code should write to an existing file, and creates a new file if it doesn't exist:

```py
with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("test")
```

But, pytest encounters an error while running this piece of code on TravisCI...

```
>           with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
E     FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'
app.py:20: FileNotFoundError
```

It works if the file exists, and it can even write to the file, but it can't create a new file... Is this even possible to do with Travis? Any help is appreciated

EDIT: This setup works even in Travis, but only if the directory exist.. in my case, I was trying to create a file in a directory before creating the directory iteself

Comment: Please post your edit as an answer.

Comment: @hoefling Will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I found out that the setup I posted does in fact work, but in my case I was attempting to create a file in a directory that didn't exist